# ios slideout navigation as second controller in navigation controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a slideout navigation controller (https://github.com/andreamazz/SlideOutNavigation) which is the second controller in a navigation controller. The navigation controller's root view controller is a login page. the slideout controller has 3 child controllers. One of the child controllers has the ability to logout, after which I would like to take the user back to the login view controller. I am trying to do this by popping to the root view controller but this doesnt seem to be the solution:

```
[[self parentViewController].navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

What needs to happen to get the root controller? thanks

Comment: Try using a delegate to tell the parent view controller to pop back to root view controller.

Comment: how exactly would that work? who would be the delegate? the page where i logout?

Comment: The child controller with logout should set up a protocol. The parent controller will set itself as the delegate to that protocol when the child is alloced. On logout, the child sends the message to its parent to pop to root.